# python script speed improvements

Tags: python, performance

for my robot I am analyzing laser range data. I need to analyze a lot of samples per second. So speed is required.
I know python is not the right language based on this - but I don't want to switch for now as I am in the prototyping phase (will see if I ever get out of it :-) ).

At the moment I am stuck on squeezing more speed out of the analyzing code I have.

I pulled out the relevant code and created a small test. It would be brilliant if someone could give me a some hints on where to improve speed in this test script.

```
from math import degrees, radians, sin, cos, fabs
import time

class NewRobotMap(object):
    def __init__(self, sizeX, sizeY, Resolution, RobotPosX, RobotPosY, RobotTheta, ServoPos, mapMaxOcc, mapMaxFree, OccValue, EmptyValue):
        self.sizeX = sizeX
        self.sizeY = sizeY
        self.RobotPosX = int(RobotPosX)
        self.RobotPosY = int(RobotPosY)
        self.mapResolution = int(Resolution)
        self.StartPosX = int(RobotPosX)
        self.StartPosY = int(RobotPosY)
        self.RobotTheta = float(RobotTheta)
        self.EmptyValue = EmptyValue
        self.ServoPos = ServoPos
        self.mapMaxOcc = mapMaxOcc
        self.mapMaxFree = mapMaxFree
        self.mapOccValue = OccValue
        self.RobotPosOldX = ""
        self.RobotPosOldY = ""

    def clear(self):
        self.RobotMap = [[self.EmptyValue for i in xrange(self.sizeY)] for j in xrange(self.sizeX)]
    def updateMap(self ,x ,y , Val):
        oldval = self.RobotMap[x][y]
        self.RobotMap[x][y]=self.RobotMap[x][y] + Val

        if self.RobotMap[x][y] > self.mapMaxOcc:
            self.RobotMap[x][y] = self.mapMaxOcc
        elif self.RobotMap[x][y] < self.mapMaxFree:
            self.RobotMap[x][y] = self.mapMaxFree
        return oldval, self.RobotMap[x][y]
    def setOcc(self,x,y):
            self.RobotMap[x][y] = self.mapMaxOcc
    def updateRobot(self,theta,x,y):
        robotThetaold=self.RobotTheta

        self.RobotTheta = float(theta)
        self.RobotPosX = int(round(self.StartPosX + float(int(x)/self.mapResolution), 0))
        self.RobotPosY = int(round(self.StartPosY - float(int(y)/self.mapResolution),0))

        if x != self.RobotPosOldX or y != self.RobotPosOldX:
            self.RobotPosOldX = x
            self.RobotPosOldY = y
            return True
        else:
            self.RobotPosOldX = x
            self.RobotPosOldY = y
            return False
    def getRobotPos(self):
        return self.RobotPosX, self.RobotPosY
    def display(self):
        s = [[str(e) for e in row] for row in self.RobotMap]
        lens = [len(max(col, key=len)) for col in zip(*s)]
        fmt = '\t'.join('{{:{}}}'.format(x) for x in lens)
        table = [fmt.format(*row) for row in s]
        print '\n'.join(table)
    def updateServoPos(self, newServoPos):
        self.ServoPos = newServoPos


templateData = {
    'MapWidth' : 800,
    'MapHeight': 600,
    'StartPosX' : 500,
    'StartPosY' : 300,
    'StartTheta' : 0,
    'Resolution' : 5,
    'mapThresholdFree' : 126,
    'mapThresholdOcc' : 130, #169
    'EmptyValue' : 128,
    'mapMaxOcc' : 137,
    'mapMaxFree' : 119,
    'ServoPos' : 0,
    'CurrentPosX' : 0,
    'CurrentPosY' : 0,
    'CurrentTheta' : 0,
    'SafeZone' : 10
}

templateData["MapHeight"] = templateData["MapHeight"] / templateData["Resolution"]
templateData["MapWidth"] = templateData["MapWidth"] / templateData["Resolution"]
templateData["StartPosX"] = templateData["StartPosX"] / templateData["Resolution"]
templateData["StartPosY"] = templateData["StartPosY"] / templateData["Resolution"]


def updateSonarCalcMapVal(val):
    mapThresholdFree = templateData["mapThresholdFree"]
    mapThresholdOcc = templateData["mapThresholdOcc"]

    #oldval
    if  val[0] <= mapThresholdFree:
        oldval = 0
    elif mapThresholdFree < val[0] < mapThresholdOcc:
        oldval = 1
    elif  val[0] >= mapThresholdOcc:
        oldval = 2

    # newval
    if  val[1] <= mapThresholdFree:
        newval = 0
    elif mapThresholdFree < val[1] < mapThresholdOcc:
        newval = 1
    elif  val[1] >= mapThresholdOcc:
        newval = 2

    if oldval != newval:
        return newval
    else:
        return 'n'


def dur( op=None, clock=[time.time()] ):
    if op != None:
        duration = time.time() - clock[0]
        print '%s finished. Duration %.6f seconds.' % (op, duration)
    clock[0] = time.time()

def updateIRWrite(RobotPos, coord, updateval):
    XtoUpdate=RobotPos[0] + coord[0]
    YtoUpdate=RobotPos[1] - coord[1]
    val = map.updateMap(XtoUpdate, YtoUpdate , updateval)
    newval=updateSonarCalcMapVal(val)

########### main Script #############

map=NewRobotMap(templateData["MapWidth"],templateData["MapHeight"], templateData["Resolution"], templateData["StartPosX"],templateData["StartPosY"], templateData["StartTheta"], templateData["ServoPos"],templateData["mapMaxOcc"],templateData["mapMaxFree"],templateData["mapThresholdOcc"],templateData["EmptyValue"])
map.clear()

dur()
for x in xrange(0,10001*40):
    updateIRWrite((100,100), (10,10), 1)
dur("loops")
```

I tried a numpy array as self.RobotMap in the NewRobotMap class/object. But this was much slower.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: You mean http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Some advices: profile the code to find the bottleneck, use `multiprocessing` to parallelize, consider JIT (PyPy or Numba).

Comment: @Danstahr: yeah, that one. Oops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few tips

## Minimize too deep redirections

Your code here:

```
def updateMap(self ,x ,y , Val):
        oldval = self.RobotMap[x][y]
        self.RobotMap[x][y]=self.RobotMap[x][y] + Val

        if self.RobotMap[x][y] > self.mapMaxOcc:
            self.RobotMap[x][y] = self.mapMaxOcc
        elif self.RobotMap[x][y] < self.mapMaxFree:
            self.RobotMap[x][y] = self.mapMaxFree
        return oldval, self.RobotMap[x][y]
```

is all the time repeating `self.RobotMap[x][y]` what requires 4 levels of hops to get the value (self -> RobotMap -> [x] -> [y])

This can be optimized:

## In place update

old:

```
self.RobotMap[x][y]=self.RobotMap[x][y] + Val
```

new (saving diving for existing value second time)

```
self.RobotMap[x][y] += Val
```

## Use local variable instead of deeply nested structure

```
def updateMap(self ,x ,y , Val):
        oldval = self.RobotMap[x][y]
        newval = oldval + Val

        if newval > self.mapMaxOcc:
            newval = self.mapMaxOcc
        elif newval < self.mapMaxFree:
            newval = self.mapMaxFree
        return oldval, newval
```

Note, that your old return `oldval, self.RobotMap[x][y]` is not only returning a value, but you have already modified the `self.RobotMap[x][y]` anyway (as it is mutable), so if you rely on that, you could be surprised.

### Using global variables instead of tempateData dictionary

Changing dictionary into global variable speeded up the run a bit as it removed one level ov indirection. I know, it looks nasty, but this may happen with optimization.

## Skip returning `self.RobotMap[x][y]`

Consider saving returning `self.RobotMap[x][y]` if this not necessary, or if you have already changed that value.

## Quick clear

change original:

```
def clear(self):
    self.RobotMap = [[self.EmptyValue for i in xrange(self.sizeY)] for j in xrange(self.sizeX)]
```

to:

```
def clear(self):
    self.RobotMap = self.sizeY * [self.sizeY * [self.EmptyValue]]
```

My test show about twice as fast execution for x = 3, y = 5, larger sizez could be even better.

## Modified code - from 0.790581 to 0.479875 seconds

```
from math import degrees, radians, sin, cos, fabs
import time

templ_MapWidth = 800
templ_MapHeight = 600
templ_StartPosX = 500
templ_StartPosY = 300
templ_StartTheta = 0
templ_Resolution = 5
templ_mapThresholdFree = 126
templ_mapThresholdOcc = 130
templ_EmptyValue = 128
templ_mapMaxOcc = 137
templ_mapMaxFree = 119
templ_ServoPos = 0
templ_CurrentPosX = 0
templ_CurrentPosY = 0
templ_CurrentTheta = 0
templ_SafeZone = 10

templ_MapHeight  = templ_MapHeight / templ_Resolution
templ_MapWidth   = templ_MapWidth /  templ_Resolution
templ_StartPosX  = templ_StartPosX / templ_Resolution
templ_StartPosY  = templ_StartPosY / templ_Resolution

class NewRobotMap(object):
    def __init__(self, sizeX, sizeY, Resolution, RobotPosX, RobotPosY, RobotTheta, ServoPos, mapMaxOcc, mapMaxFree, OccValue, EmptyValue):
        self.sizeX = sizeX
        self.sizeY = sizeY
        self.RobotPosX = int(RobotPosX)
        self.RobotPosY = int(RobotPosY)
        self.mapResolution = int(Resolution)
        self.StartPosX = int(RobotPosX)
        self.StartPosY = int(RobotPosY)
        self.RobotTheta = float(RobotTheta)
        self.EmptyValue = EmptyValue
        self.ServoPos = ServoPos
        self.mapMaxOcc = mapMaxOcc
        self.mapMaxFree = mapMaxFree
        self.mapOccValue = OccValue
        self.RobotPosOldX = ""
        self.RobotPosOldY = ""

    def clear(self):
        self.RobotMap = self.sizeX * [self.sizeY * [self.EmptyValue]]

    def updateMap(self, x, y, Val):
        oldval = self.RobotMap[x][y]
        newval = oldval + Val

        if newval < self.mapMaxFree:
            return oldval, self.mapMaxFree
        if newval > self.mapMaxOcc:
            return oldval, self.mapMaxOcc
        return oldval, newval

    def setOcc(self, x, y):
            self.RobotMap[x][y] = self.mapMaxOcc

    def updateRobot(self, theta, x, y):
        robotThetaold = self.RobotTheta

        self.RobotTheta = float(theta)
        self.RobotPosX = int(round(self.StartPosX + float(int(x)/self.mapResolution), 0))
        self.RobotPosY = int(round(self.StartPosY - float(int(y)/self.mapResolution), 0))

        if x != self.RobotPosOldX or y != self.RobotPosOldX:
            self.RobotPosOldX = x
            self.RobotPosOldY = y
            return True
        else:
            self.RobotPosOldX = x
            self.RobotPosOldY = y
            return False

    def getRobotPos(self):
        return self.RobotPosX, self.RobotPosY

    def display(self):
        s = [[str(e) for e in row] for row in self.RobotMap]
        lens = [len(max(col, key=len)) for col in zip(*s)]
        fmt = '\t'.join('{{:{}}}'.format(x) for x in lens)
        table = [fmt.format(*row) for row in s]
        print '\n'.join(table)

    def updateServoPos(self, newServoPos):
        self.ServoPos = newServoPos

def updateSonarCalcMapVal(org, new):
    mapThresholdFree = templ_mapThresholdFree
    mapThresholdOcc = templ_mapThresholdOcc

    #oldval
    if  org <= mapThresholdFree:
        oldval = 0
    elif mapThresholdFree < org < mapThresholdOcc:
        oldval = 1
    elif  org >= mapThresholdOcc:
        oldval = 2

    # newval
    if  new <= mapThresholdFree:
        newval = 0
    elif mapThresholdFree < new < mapThresholdOcc:
        newval = 1
    elif  new >= mapThresholdOcc:
        newval = 2

    if oldval != newval:
        return newval
    else:
        return 'n'


def dur(op=None, clock=[time.time()]):
    if op != None:
        duration = time.time() - clock[0]
        print '%s finished. Duration %.6f seconds.' % (op, duration)
    clock[0] = time.time()

def updateIRWrite(RobotPos, coord, updateval):
    XtoUpdate = RobotPos[0] + coord[0]
    YtoUpdate = RobotPos[1] - coord[1]

    newval = updateSonarCalcMapVal(*mymap.updateMap(XtoUpdate, YtoUpdate, updateval))

########### main Script #############

mymap = NewRobotMap(templ_MapWidth, templ_MapHeight, templ_Resolution, templ_StartPosX, templ_StartPosY, templ_StartTheta, templ_ServoPos, templ_mapMaxOcc, templ_mapMaxFree, templ_mapThresholdOcc, templ_EmptyValue)
mymap.clear()

dur()

for x in xrange(0, 10001*40):
    updateIRWrite((100, 100), (10, 10), 1)

dur("loops")
```

## Conclusions

The code definitely needs review for doing correct work. E.g. there are methods, which are not used at all and other calls, which never use returned value.

But some optimization could be shown. Generally, following is good to follow:

1. Make your code running correctly first
2. Clarify what is acceptable speed, do not optimize, if not necessary
3. Measure, profile
4. Start optimizing in busiest loops, there are best chances to speed things up. In them, each line of code counts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your tips. Some points of hte code may seem unnecessary - but that's because of the missing context. Removing the too deep redirections helped a lot - about 10% more speed. I'll dig through the code for similar optimizations.

Comment: @robvoi You are welcome. I am sure, that after you refactor your code few times, you will get cleaner code, which often leads to more efficient one too. Consider checking PEP 008 http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ what can make your code easier to read - it will help even you. Sometime, restructuring classes (good you use them) might put needed data closer to logical use. Also having test cases (I use `nose` for this) is great help. And of course the loops. But go step by step and you will become master of Python speed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you install PyPy and run your script with it instead of CPython (the default) ?  It should work as a drop-in replacement of CPython.

- http://pypy.org/

It is based on (tracing?) JIT and famous for its high runtime performance.

- http://speed.pypy.org/

Comment: Thanks. Pypy is much faster - at least in the test where values repeat a lot. I'll check in the live scenario.